# Swagger / Open API based on JSON example

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, documentation, openapi

Given a JSON document / sample which is the request payload for the API endpoint  - is there a way to generate a Swagger / Open API specification?

Comment: https://swaggerhub.com/

Comment: @BillHorvath  I am not talking about importing a JSON spec. I am asking if the spec can be extracted out of a JSON example.